# Display image from String Imageurl

Tags: android

I have image url in string as

```
String imgurl=days.getString("icon_url");
```

getting this url `jsonarray` which is saved in shared preference 
how to show this string image url into `ImageView`?

Any help???

Comment: @Zaib Niaz, If you just want to show Image in ImageView fro URL. You need this https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader OR https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: url is in for loop and 
 url has to change after every loop??
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use UniversalImageLoader or picasso Library to load image in imageview from url.

Add internet permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And to download image using AsyncTask use following code:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    } 

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try { 
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return mIcon11;
    } 

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    } 
}
```

And to use above code to load image from url in imageview use following code:

```
new DownloadImageTask(mImageView).execute(imgurl);
```

Comment: i did it but image quality is so poor
how i can make it looks better...??

Comment: can you please share your imageurl? may be the image on server is not in good quality

Comment: http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif
this is the image un uri

Comment: have you specified width and height of your imageview

Comment: yes..
i did in xml width by fill parent and height by wrap content

Comment: your original image height and width is 50 * 50 and you are stretching it that's why the image quality is very poor.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion..!!
i will check it and let you know by applying that trick..:)

Comment: that trick doesn't work ..!!
:(

Comment: i have checked it by fixing height and width but same blur image appears in different sizes as declared.

Comment: set height and width to wrap_content

Comment: nope
i checked it..!!
i think problem occurs during downloading